How to cite a conditionally accepted article?
I'm currently working on an R&R with a fairly strict due date coming up within a few weeks. One of the reviewers had a question about a small part of the paper that uses data from a particular source, Organization X. I know of another paper that uses different data from Org X that just got conditionally accepted elsewhere, and I'd like to cite this other paper as evidence that Org X data is reputable. Is citing it as "forthcoming in journal Y" appropriate, even though it has only been conditionally accepted? Should I wait until that paper is accepted to put it in as a reference? Is there something else I haven't considered? Thanks so much!

The "condition" you mention is an important consideration.

Is the "due date" just for submission? Will your work go through review and revision?

Not sure what the conditions for acceptance were for the other paper – I believe it was addressing 1-2 minor points. But for me, the R&R due date is for a second round of review and, (I hope), revision before publication.

Is this paper on a preprint server that you can cite?

Can you state Unpublished?


Is citing it as "forthcoming in journal Y" appropriate, even though it has only been conditionally accepted?

You should only write that the paper is "forthcoming" or "to appear" in a journal if the paper has in fact been accepted for publication in that journal.
The problem with "conditional acceptance" is that it doesn't convey precisely how easy/likely it would be for the author to meet the conditions for acceptance. One might reasonably assume that final acceptance is probable once you reach a "conditionally accepted" status, but it is not guaranteed. So I think you want to be careful about giving an inaccurate impression of the paper's status. "Forthcoming" sounds like too strong of a claim to make at this point.
There may be hypothetical exceptions to this, where what should really be described as a proper acceptance is described in a way that creates an appearance of being "conditional", but those cases don't seem that common to me. If based on what you know about the paper's status, you really feel that acceptance is nothing more than a formality at this point, I suppose you can take the chance and describe the paper as forthcoming. But if I were you I'd want to be ready with a very good explanation of why this description makes sense, and to have a very good reason for even bothering to put myself in a position where I'm making statements that people might find misleading or eyebrow-raising.

Should I wait until that paper is accepted to put it in as a reference?

Regardless of whether the paper is accepted, you are free to cite it. This would make more sense if the paper is publicly available as a preprint. It might make a little sense even if the paper is not publicly available but its existence is public knowledge and easy to confirm. In a situation where neither the paper nor its existence are public knowledge, you can still cite it, but such a citation may not carry much weight or lend your claims about Org X's data the sort of credibility you are hoping it would.
If you cite the paper, listing it as a preprint or as "submitted", you can add a footnote explaining that you have been informed that it is conditionally accepted, if you feel that is helpful.

Saying the paper is "forthcoming" is overly optimistic unless you know the details. It might even be withdrawn by the authors if they don't agree with the condition.
For a submission that is subject to review and revision yourself, you can add a note that the paper is under review and has been conditionally accepted. Then, when it comes time to revise your own work you can update that with the current state.
Make sure, however, that if the paper isn't, in fact, accepted/published that you are covered in what you say. Don't make your own work dependent on the unknown factors associate with someone else's work.
But initial submissions can normally be revised before publication. It is fairly rare that things are published as first submitted and notes to reviewers can be fine. Submissions to conferences, of course, have tighter deadlines and fewer opportunities for revision.
If you need to formally/finally cite a paper that is under review, even if late in the process, my choice would be to list it as "in preparation". Saying more is problematic.
